# Reseting Bash Prompt Text(Not the color) on RPi

Tags: raspbian, bash

I changed my bash prompt text to just the "π" sign. I really want to change it back to the default but I don't want to reset the WHOLE Pi. I've been looking around on this site and I can't find anything. The linux command I got from http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html doesn't work either. Is there a way to edit `/.bash_profile` so I can get the default back. Thanks.(I'm running raspbian by the way) I tried to run:

```
pi $ sudo grep -d skip "PS1" /home/pi
```

But it just returned:

```
pi $
```

Comment: How did you change it? what file did you edit? You may not have a ~/.bash_profile but a ~/.bashrc file instead.

Comment: Could you edit your question and paste the output of the following command sudo grep -d skip "PS1" /home/pi/.*

Comment: Steve Robillard , I made a ~/.bash_profile file as directed on https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/learn-the-command-line then changed prompt as directed on www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html

Comment: @BradenParks The command was  sudo grep -d skip "PS1" /home/pi/.* (notice the /.* after /home/pi).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get back the default, you can copy the default configuration files from `/etc/skel`.

```
% ls -a /etc/skel
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .profile
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just change the prompt by setting variable PS1.

```
export PS1="pi $ "
```

for example, for the shell you're in.  But more generally, just change whatever edit you made to set the prompt to π in the first place?

Comment: That doesn't work it just changes it to "pi $" not to the default setting.